# Merge two pandas dataframes based on depth range

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge

I would like to merge two dataframe on columns Id and top_depth and bottom_depth.
I would like the take each record from the left df and, if available, assign a record from the right df if 'depth' falls between 'top_depth' and 'bottom_depth'.

Here is an exemple of the dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
     ['a', 27, 29, 10],
     ['a', 29, 30, 2.5],
     ['a', 30, 32.5, 56],
     ['a', 32.5, 36, 18],
     ['a', 36, 39, 5],
     ['b', 0, 3, 0.5],
     ['b', 3, 6, 1.5],
     ['b', 6, 9, 2.5]]),
     columns=['name', 'top_depth', 'bottom_depth', 'attr1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
     ['a', 0, 25, 'alpha'],
     ['a', 25, 28, 'beta'],
     ['a', 28, 39, 'gamma'],
     ['b', 0, 6, 'alpha'],
     ['b', 6, 9, 'beta'],
     ['b', 9, 18, 'phi'],
     ['b', 18, 25, 'teta']]),
     columns=['name', 'top_depth', 'bottom_depth', 'attr2'])
```

Then merge to get this:

```
>>> df3 
   name top_depth bottom_depth attr1   attr2
0     a         0           25   NaN   alpha
1     a        25           27   NaN    beta
2     a        27           28    10    beta
2     a        28           29    10   gamma
3     a        29           30   2.5   gamma
4     a        30         32.5    56   gamma
5     a      32.5           36    18   gamma
6     a        36           39     5   gamma
7     b         0            3   0.5   alpha
8     b         3            6   1.5   alpha
9     b         6            9   2.5    beta
10    b         9           18   NaN     phi
11    b        18           25   NaN    teta
```

Is there an easy way to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

This gets you close:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name', suffixes=('', '_r'))

keep = (merged.top_depth >= merged.top_depth_r) & (merged.bottom_depth <= merged.bottom_depth_r)

print merged.loc[keep, ['name', 'top_depth', 'bottom_depth', 'attr1', 'attr2']]
```

Yields:

```
   name top_depth bottom_depth attr1  attr2 
2     a        27           29    10  gamma 
5     a        29           30   2.5  gamma 
8     a        30         32.5    56  gamma 
11    a      32.5           36    18  gamma 
14    a        36           39     5  gamma 
15    b         0            3   0.5  alpha 
19    b         3            6   1.5  alpha 
24    b         6            9   2.5   beta
```

I don't know how you want the row:

```
   name top_depth bottom_depth attr1   attr2
0     a         0           25   NaN   alpha
1     a        25           27   NaN    beta
```

In your question you asked for a left join.  These rows are more like a right join.  Let me know if this is close to what you're after and I can try to help more.

Comment: thanks it is close. Actually, I slightly modified my original question to reflect more my need. I have to split the first row of 'df1' (27-->28 and 28-->29) as the depth range of 'df2' is not equal to the depth range of 'df1'. I think this is more tricky to do...